# Documentation review item overflows into the footer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, documentation, design

I just got a ping from documentation with review items. Whilst trying to scroll down to find the changes made, the footer of the page duplicated and obstructed the screen and the header appears to have done the same except to the right. The top header also seems to have vanished and turned into hyperlinks under the documentation header

[image: Screenshot showing bug]

I'm using Firefox on windows and my resolution is set to 2048x1152.

Comment: o.O Well, that's a new one. :) Unfortunately, I can't reproduce what you're seeing. Do you have a link to the review item that caused this still handy? Does it happen every time you try to view it? Do you have the new-style top navigation enabled or is it still the old off-black topbar?

Comment: @AdamLear http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/getting-started-with-python-language/discussion?page=1&pagesize=30&tab=active&type=all#itemid=125056&itemtype=proposedchanges&commentId=19928 is the link to that review from my pings, it doesn't appear in my web history at all. I'm on the old style topbar and I can't reproduce it now. Scrolled down, scrolled up again and clicked the reject button; did some more scrolling whilst it waited to send (button unresponsive)

Comment: Well, I'm gonna mark this as no-repro for now. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Give me a shout if you get it to happen again (ideally consistently). Thanks!